# How to access this JSON data using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

NodeJs: (Service call)

```
router.route('/getProAtribute')
.post(function(req,res,next){
ProductData.find({},{'_id':0,'attribute':1},function(err,productDatas){
if(!err){res.json(productDatas);}
else{res.json({'status':'no data or error'});}
});
});
```

Schema:

```
var product_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
product_id:{type:Number},
product_name:{type:String},
product_image:{type:String},
product_image_type:{type:String},
category_id:{type:Number},
category_name:{type:String},
attribute:{type:[]}
})
var ProductData = module.exports = mongoose.model('productData', product_schema);
```

JSON output:

```
[{"_id":"5693413efc055b0011ac7891","attribute:[{"Size":"asd","Brand":"asds","product_id":"1"}]},{"_id":"569cb82c079bfa80094dc936","attribute":[{"Size":"SA","Brand":"123","product_id":"2"}]}]
```

NOTE: in attribute keys will change dynamically(size,color,type, price etc....)

So i need to print key and value in the front end.

Comment: You must provide details. Do you reeive this data from a REST Service? What is your backend?

Comment: you have to give us back end code , both code needs to match .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
{{value._id}}
<div ng-repeat="(key,values) in value.attribute">
{{values.Size}}  {{values.Brand}}
Key: {{key}}
</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data">
{{value._id}}
{{value.attribute[0].Size}}<!--For static you can use $index in place of 0-->
</div>
```

Comment: if attribute array keys are varying(changing dynamically) then? how to print those key and value ?? Please help me .

Comment: I have edited the answer.. check it works fine for dynamically for attribute array